# Create a list of lists from one list by uniques

Tags: python, json, algorithm, list, sorting

I'm trying to convert the following list:

```
[1,2,2,4,2,1,5,4,3]
```

To this list of lists:

```
[[1,1],[2,2],[3],[4,4],[5]]
```

Does anyone know a quick way to do this? I'm going to be running this on a very long list. This is in python.

Comment: This is a bad question because it doesn't show what you've tried or that you have any understanding of the problem. It's clear what you're asking, but a good StackOverflow question will also demonstrate why you're having trouble with it.  That being said, what you're looking to do can be easily done with a sort followed by a reduce.

Comment: 1- What does this have to do with JSON? 2- Your result list doesn't make sense as written (I assume there should be a third 2 in the list of lists?) At least describe what you're wanting the result list to be.

Comment: Sort the list. Create a new list of lists. Append the items in the list to the last list in the list of lists.

Comment: Why do you have this tagged JSON?

Answer (score 3):

Her you go:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> [list(g) for k, g in groupby(sorted([1,2,2,4,2,1,5,4,3]))]
[[1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3], [4, 4], [5]]
```

If by 'long list' you may want to sort the list in place before grouping, you can do:

```
>>> li.sort()
>>> [list(g) for k, g in groupby(li)]
[[1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3], [4, 4], [5]]
```

Even better still (but unspecified in your question) is if you could leave the groups as iterators that would be calculated as needed, you can do:

```
>>> for k, grp in groupby(li):
...    print k, grp
... 
1 <itertools._grouper object at 0x106ded210>
2 <itertools._grouper object at 0x106ded190>
3 <itertools._grouper object at 0x106ded210>
4 <itertools._grouper object at 0x106ded190>
5 <itertools._grouper object at 0x106ded210>
```

Then the items in `grp` are calculated (once) as you need them, as seen here:

```
>>> for k, grp in groupby(li):
...    print k, list(grp)
... 
1 [1, 1]
2 [2, 2, 2]
3 [3]
4 [4, 4]
5 [5]
```

Comment: For long lists, as the OP mentioned, `.sort()` might actually be more beneficial than `sorted` as it sorts in-place.